# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, array

Não consigo resolver o erro que aparece no código. Estou com uma matriz de rotação, tentando calcular forças rotacionais, ou seja, força radial, axial e tangencial.

```
Ft2 = np.zeros([janelaanalise,])
Fr2 = np.zeros([janelaanalise,])
Fa2 = np.zeros([janelaanalise,])

i3=0
for i3 in range(janelaanalise):
  Fxyz = np.array([Fxanalise[i3],Fyanalise[i3],Fzanalise[i3]])

  #######
  matrotacao = np.array([(np.sin(a),-np.cos(a),0),(-np.cos(a),-np.sin(a),0),(0,0,1)])
  #######
  Ftra = matrotacao @ Fxyz
  Ft2[i3]   = Ftra[0]
  Fr2[i3]   = Ftra[1]
  Fa2[i3]   = Ftra[2]
```

Erro que aparece:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:10:
> VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested
> sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays
> with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do
> this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray   #
> Remove the CWD from sys.path while we load stuff.
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 11   #######
> 12   Ftra = matrotacao @ Fxyz
> ---> 13   Ft2[i3]   = Ftra[0]
> 14   Fr2[i3]   = Ftra[1]
> 15   Fa2[i3]   = Ftra[2]
>
> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Comment: O que são as variáveis `janelaanalise`, `Fxanalise`, `Fyanalise` e `Fzanalise`? Tente deixar o código mais completo possível, caso contrário é difícil de encontrar a fonte do erro.

Comment: Esse é o código completo? Tenta acrescentar o código completo pra melhor compreensão. Por gentileza.

Comment: T = janelaanalise * dt
n = janelaanalise
t = tempojanelavisualizacao
data = Fyjanelavisual
y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data, method='gust')
plt.figure(figsize=(16,5))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(tempojanelavisualizacao, data, 'b-', linewidth=1, label='data')
plt.plot(tempojanelavisualizacao, y, 'g-', linewidth=2, label='filtered data')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(tempojanelavisualizacao, y, 'g-', linewidth=1, label='filtered data')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.35)
plt.show()

Comment: enviei o código mais completo, mas virou o samba do crioulo doido